# How to verify key length of a PEM certificate using openSSL functions

Tags: c, https, openssl, pem

How do I verify the key length of a PEM certificate that is generated in this way:

```
# openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
# openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
# cp server.key server.key.org
# openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
# openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

What I need is a C function using procedures from OpenSSL, that performs validation on a PEM certificate (I use it for the lighttpd HTTPS server), and returns the length of the key stored in the certificate (in this case, 1024).

Comment: The command lines you want are `openssl verify cert.pem` and `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text` (dumps out the certificate data, including the key length) but I don't know how that maps to the C functions.

Comment: Thanks Rup, I knew about the openssl verify command, but I need to check it programatically from C, not from the command line.

Comment: I found a way to do this; please see code below. I tested this under Linux and Mac OS X 10.7, but 10.7 will complain about deprecated methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some tweaking, I believe have found the right routines.

The following should get you started with exploring other OpenSSL routines, in case you need to handle other types of certificates ([x509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/x509.html#), [pem](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html#)).

Also read through your local `x509.h` and `pem.h` for structures and functions that will recover other information you're after.

```
/* Compile with 'gcc -Wall -lcrypto foo.c' or similar...
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   $ ./a.out server.crt
   Opened: server.crt
   RSA Public Key: (1024 bit) 

   $ ./a.out server.key
   ERROR: could not read x509 data from server.key                
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    X509 *x509 = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *public_key = NULL;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp) {
        PEM_read_X509(fp, &x509, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);

        if (x509) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Opened PEM certificate file: %s\n", argv[1]);
            /* do stuff with certificate... */
            public_key = X509_get_pubkey(x509);
            if (public_key) {
                switch (public_key->type) {
                    case EVP_PKEY_RSA:
                        fprintf(stdout, "RSA Public Key: (%d bit)\n", BN_num_bits(public_key->pkey.rsa->n));
                        break;
                    default:
                        fprintf(stdout, "Unknown public key type? See OpenSSL documentation\n");
                        break;
                }
                EVP_PKEY_free(public_key);
            }
            X509_free(x509);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not read x509 data from %s\n", argv[1]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open file!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```