# Getting the public key length of an X509 certificate

Tags: c, openssl

Given a certificate in an `X509` object, I'd like to figure out the length of its public key, similarly to [this CLI command](https://www.shellhacks.com/openssl-find-ssl-key-length-linux-command-line/):

```
$ openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout | grep "Public-Key"
RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

I can't seem to find a way to extract that piece of information from the C API.

I found [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835597/how-to-verify-key-length-of-a-pem-certificate-using-openssl-functions), but it seems to rely on accessing `EVP_PKEY`'s internals, which I can't do as I can get an incomplete type error:

```
server.c:233:27: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘EVP_PKEY {aka struct evp_pkey_st}’
         switch (public_key->type) {
                           ^~
```

Comment: What is the exact wording of your _incomplete type_ error?  And if by _accessing EVP_PKEY's internals, which_ ***I can't do as I can get an incomplete type error.***, are you providing all of the information in the prototype: `EVP_PKEY *PEM_read_PUBKEY(FILE *fp, EVP_PKEY **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);`  (eg, like `password` ?)

Comment: I would suggest changing the phrase _which I can't do as I can get an incomplete type errro._  to:  _which I have tried, but get an [use exact error message wording here] error_

Comment: @ryyker Thanks for the input, I've updated my question with the exact error.

Comment: Read the error message literally.  On line 233 your code is trying to access the value stored at the location public_key->...  It's telling you it does not like the struck pointer symbol.  Either the member ..._key is an array and needs the array braces [..] or it is not a pointer?  In which case  change the -> to a dot (.)

Comment: ...BTW,  I used the word 'access' as a replacement for the more commonly used word 'dereference',

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly access members of `EVP_PKEY` structure since they are not available on public API of recent versions of OpenSSL.

OpenSSL, however, provides access to some of these parameters by `EVP_PKEY_get*` functions.

So if you know that the X509 certificate you want to interrogate contains an RSA key, then you can first get a reference to an RSA structure by calling [`EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA.html) and then get the size of modulus in bits by calling [`RSA_bits`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_bits.html)

The code should look somewhat like this:

```
EVP_PKEY *pub_key = ...;
RSA *rsa = EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA(pub_key);

printf("EVP_PKEY_size(pub_key): %d\n", RSA_bits(rsa));
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's how to do that for an elliptic curve key:

```cpp
EVP_PKEY* pub_key = X509_get0_pubkey(x509);

if (EVP_PKEY_base_id(pub_key) == EVP_PKEY_EC) {
    printf("EVP_PKEY_bits(pub_key): %d\n", EVP_PKEY_bits(pub_key));
}
```